# Pandas: Coerce errors while reading CSV

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

The `pandas.to_datetime` function has an `errors` keyword argument, that if set to 'coerce' will replace any values that it fails to cast with `NaT`.

Is there a way to replicate that functionality in `pandas.read_csv` while it's casting the columns?

For example, if I have the following data in a CSV file:

```
a,c
0,a
1,b
2,c
a,d
```

And I try:

```
pd.read_csv("file.csv", dtype={"a":"int64", "c":'object'})
```

It throws an error saying that it was unable to convert column `a` to type `int64`.

Is there a way to read a CSV with pandas so that if it fails while casting a column to fill a failed value with `NaN` or something that I specify?

Comment: use `Int64` (notice the capital "I")

Comment: Instead of `int64`, you can use `pd.Int64Dtype()`. That will work even if you have `NaN` values.

Comment: Perhaps read the CSV into a DataFrame, **then** clean your data and change the data types as desired.

Comment: I agree with @S3DEV, although it would be good to have more information on the actual data/problem.

Comment: An option might be as said above, then use the .astype() function; into which an ‘errors’ arg can be passed with ‘ignore’ as the value.  Per the docs: “ ignore : suppress exceptions. On error return original object.”.  Granted, it’s not the exact outcome you’re after, but maybe a half way house.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution that might work for you; or at least get you going in a direction.

### Caveat:

AFIK what you're after, is not possible - i.e.: an `int64` column with a `NaN` value because `NaN` is a `float` data type.  Additionally, there is no need to convert column `c` to `object`, as this is implied.

### Suggested Solution:

First, read your CSV without casting data types. Then, clean your data / convert your data types.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Just pretend this is reading from a CSV.
data = {'a': [0, 1, 2, 'a'],
        'c': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

**Original Dataset:**

```
   a  c
0  0  a
1  1  b
2  2  c
3  a  d 

a    object
c    object
dtype: object
```

**Convert column `a`:**
Using the `pd.to_numeric` function, you can do something similar to `to_datetime` by coercing any errors to `NaN`.  However, this converts your column to `float64`, as `NaN` is a `float` data type.

```
df['a'] = pd.to_numeric(df['a'], errors='coerce')
```

**Output:**

```
     a  c
0  0.0  a
1  1.0  b
2  2.0  c
3  NaN  d 

a    float64
c     object
dtype: object
```

**Convert column `a` to `int64`:**
If you must have column `a` as an integer, you can do this:

```
df['a'] = df['a'].replace(np.nan, 0).astype(np.int64)
```

**Output:**

```
   a  c
0  0  a
1  1  b
2  2  c
3  0  d 

a     int64
c    object
dtype: object
```

Hope this gets you started.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another solution that does it at read time. You can pass manual conversion function to csv reading as `pd.read_csv(..., converters=...)`.

For your case, you should pass `converters={'a': convert_to_none_coerce_if_not}` where `convert_to_none_coerce_if_not` can be:

```py
import numpy as np

def convert_to_none_coerce_if_not(val: str):
    try:
        if int(str) == float(str):
            # string is int
            return np.int16(str)
        else:
            # string is numeric, but a float
            return np.nan
    except ValueError as e:
        # string cannot be parsed as a number, return nan
        return np.nan
```